# simple_calendar week calendar by one day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I'm implementing a calendar displaying a weekly schedule by hours. I need something like this:

[image: Week calendar by hour]

[`simple_calendar`](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar) is a perfect gem for making simple calendars with events,

[image: Simple use of week calendar]

but I can't figure out how to make it group not by days but by hours.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the view using

```
rails g simple_calendar:views
```

Then render the week calender like this

```
<%= week_calendar  events: @appointments do |date, appointments| %>
    <span class="date-str"><%= date.day %></span>
  <div class="row">
    #your hours logic...
    <% (1..24).each do |h|%>
      #deal with you hour view and render with some identifier 
      <label><%= h%></label>
    <% end %>
  </div>
    <% appointments.each do |appointment| %>
        <div>
          <%= appointment.name %>
        </div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then manage the simple_calender/_week_calendar.html.erb view.
I think its little bit helpful for you.

Comment: I created a small demo app using simple_calender gem [link](https://fast-escarpment-67237.herokuapp.com/) and github code [link](https://github.com/kvivek1115/slot-booking)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and time, I will try this tomorrow and let you know how did it end up. p.s. Unfortunately, I can't gave you upvote

Comment: Thanks @vivek. With this weekly view, does it put the event in the correct start time row? Does it represent event on the time axis? ie: An event for 9am - 5pm will go from 9am on the y axis, all the way to 5pm on the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

This gem cannot do that. But you can make it and create a pull request.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice. What do you purpose? Maybe full_calendar gem? I don't have knowledge to make that my own.

Comment: Not an answer sir!